# Step line Chart(DevExtreme) width is not correct at the first load

Tags: angular, charts

Initial chart width is 400 and when I change width of window then its width becomes 100%.
Please let me know if anybody knows why this occurs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/im5AE.png

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if the chart's container is not visible on the first rendering or has the zero size.  
To avoid this, you can call [the render method](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxChart/Methods/#render). Alternatively, check your markup to fix the container size.